# JQuery Form Message Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validation working for this form and for the most part it is working. The problem arises is solely when I write something in the "Message" input field and click submit. Instead of preventing the form from being submitted, the form is submitted.

Upon submission in the Chrome console I can see the following:
"Cannot read property 'call' of undefined jquery.validate.min.js"

```
var $taskForm = $("#task-form").validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true
            },
            'assign[]' : {
                required : true
            },
            checkin : {
                required : true
            },
            start : {
                required : true
            },
            completion : {
                required : true

            },
            message : {
                required : true,
                maxLength: 200,
                minlength : 10
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : 'Please enter a name for this task',
            },
            'assign[]' :{
                required : 'Please choose someone to assign this task to',
            },
            checkin : {
                required : 'Please choose a date',
            },
            completion : {
                required : 'Please choose a date',
            },
            message : {
                required : 'Please enter a description for the task'
            }
        },

        // Ajax form submition
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success : function() {
                    $("#task-form").addClass('submited');
                }
            });
        }


    });
```

Comment: Did you remember to include the jquery form plugin?  ajaxSubmit is not part of the jquery library. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Comment: Use the uncompressed version of jquery.validate and debug the code. Enable "break on exceptions" (the encircled pause sign). This should give you a clue regarding the issue.

Comment: `maxLength` is not `maxlength`, that's the sum of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, you should not have a comma at the end of your required messages.

```
var $taskForm = $("#task-form").validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true
            },
            'assign[]' : {
                required : true
            },
            checkin : {
                required : true
            },
            start : {
                required : true
            },
            completion : {
                required : true

            },
            message : {
                required : true,
                maxLength: 200,
                minlength : 10
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : 'Please enter a name for this task'
            },
            'assign[]' :{
                required : 'Please choose someone to assign this task to'
            },
            checkin : {
                required : 'Please choose a date'
            },
            completion : {
                required : 'Please choose a date'
            },
            message : {
                required : 'Please enter a description for the task'
            }
        },

        // Ajax form submition
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success : function() {
                    $("#task-form").addClass('submited');
                }
            });
        }


    });
```